# Can you pass options to a linux kernel module through the boot parameter?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I have an issue that is fixed by changing the lpfc driver to run using MSI interrupts. This is done by adding “options lpfc lpfc_use_msi=2” /etc/modprobe.conf.local file.

Is there a way to make this change using kernel boot parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Linux kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
Module parameters for modules that are built into the kernel image
are specified on the kernel command line with the module name plus
'.' plus parameter name, with '=' and value if appropriate, such as:

    usbcore.blinkenlights=1
```

Note that this is for modules that are built into the kernel. If it is compiled as a loadable module, it will have to be modprobe'd sometime after the kernel starts, and this is the correct time to pass parameters to the module.

Comment: The module is not built into the kernel. How do you pass parameters to the module when it loads if it is not compiled into the kernel?

Comment: @countingtoten In /etc/modprobe.conf or related, as you originally found.